# R - dplyr function count lazyeval error

Tags: r, dplyr

I actually have two related questions.

The first concerns the inclusions of `dplyr::count` in a function. 
I am writing a function to compute proportions (`%`). 
The function works perfectly when I use `group_by`, such as

```
library(dplyr) 
library(lazyeval)

dprop = function(data, ...) {
  data %>% group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))%>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    mutate(n = n / sum(n))
}
```

(on a random dataset)

```
 mtcars %>% dprop(am, gear)

     am  gear         n
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     0     3 0.7894737
2     0     4 0.2105263
3     1     4 0.6153846
4     1     5 0.3846154
```

However, when I write it using `count`, it doesn't work

```
dprop2 = function(data, ...) {
  data %>% 
    count_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
    mutate(n = n / sum(n))
}
```

Why ?

The second question concerns the inclusion of a second `grouping` in the function. Sometimes when calculating proportions, I need to change *base* such as

```
group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
       summarise(n = n()) %>% 
        group_by(UNIQUEVAR) %>% 
       mutate(n = n / sum(n))
```

I tried to include another variable in the function but it doesn't work

```
dprop = function(data, UNIQUEVAR, ...) {
  data %>% group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
     group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy(UNIQUEVAR)) %>% 
    mutate(n = n / sum(n))
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: in count you should be using `vars` not `.dots`. the second you want to use mutate instead of summarise? using summarise drops variables including the eventual `UNIQUEVAR`

Comment: Can you show me an example ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I finally found

With `count`

```
dprop = function(data, ...) {
  data %>% 
    count_(vars = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
    mutate(n = n / sum(n))
}
```

And a different grouping

```
dprop_group = function(data, ...) {
  data %>% 
    count_(vars = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...) ) %>% 
    mutate(n = n / sum(n)) %>% 
    group_by(group_col) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}
```